# Android build errors in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

when *I build my android game in unity 2019*, I run it in my mobile and just blue screen was found.
plz help me because this is my first game I've made.

## in build settings I think***

plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should check logs.
2. Make sure created scene correctly. (Unity default scene is blue so be aware centered your items.
3. Maybe you don't apply your scene.

File -> Building Settings -> Scenes In Building
Select your scene. (If it isn't on the list, click "Add Open scenes", it will show.)

Comment: ArgumentException: Getting control 8's position in a group with only 8 controls when doing repaint
Aborting